# Cookie и поддомены

Tags: cookie, поддомены

Здравствуйте,

Есть несколько сайтов на поддоменах s1.site.ru, s2.site.ru, s3.site.ru.
Как можно создать cookie, доступную для всех поддоменов?
Но чтобы не создавалась эта кука для каждного поддомена, а была только одна, доступнка для всех поддоменов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите куки для домена site.ru. они будут видны на поддоменах этого сайта